# jQuery .prepend() text to anchor tag is clickable. I only want plain text

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add some text before all links that follow a certain pattern with jQuery.

If a link follows this structure:

`<a href="//example.com/u/foo/">foo</a>`

I want to add the text *"Listed by: "* before it.

I can target the links using:

`$("a[href*='/u/']")`

And it works. The text is added.

---

The issue is that I don't want the added text to be a part of the clickable `<a>` tag.

What I am trying to achieve is this:

```html
<span>Listed by: <a href="#">Foo</a></span>
```

But instead I'm getting this:

```html
<a href="#"><span>Listed by: </span>Foo</a>
```

---

I don't want *"Listed by: "* to be clickable. I want it as plain text.

Here's my full code:

```js
$("p>small.text-muted>a[href*='/u/']").prepend("<span class='listed-by'>Listed by: </span>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <small class="text-muted">
    <a href="/example.com/category/bar/">bar</a> | <a href="//example.com/u/foo/">foo</a> | 2 views
  </small>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the span need to wrap around the anchor? You may be able to use insertBefore(). Note the content and element order are switched from prepend().

```js
$("<span class='listed-by'>Listed by: </span>").insertBefore("p>small.text-muted>a[href*='/u/']");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <small class="text-muted">
    <a href="/example.com/category/bar/">bar</a> | <a href="//example.com/u/foo/">foo</a> | 2 views
  </small>
</p>
```

Comment: No it does not need to be wrapped around the anchor. This answers the question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can make a work around like this

```
var oldHtml = $("a[href*='/u/']").html(); // You retrieved all anchor element
var newHtml = "<span> Listed by: " + oldHtml + "</span>";
$(".text-muted").html(newHtml);
```

I hope this might work !

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have selected the other answer because it works and was posted 2 minutes before yours.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try doing this way ?

```js
$("p>small.text-muted>span").append("<a href='//example.com/u/foo/'>foo</a>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <small class="text-muted">
<a href="/example.com/category/bar/">bar</a> | <span class='listed-by'>Listed by: </span> | 2 views
  </small>
</p>
```

Comment: this is a good idea but won't work because `<a href='//example.com/u/foo/'>foo</a>` is dynamically generated and changes  on every page.